# Absolute value of double and integer contained in array

Tags: c, arrays

I need to get absolute value of (double) and value of one integer from array of integers (all declared inside function)

for my developing program is fine to use

```
int serv[10];
double m;

x=fabs(m-serV[i]);
```

i get the value and go on, but if i try to compile it with g++,it won't let me and following error occures:

> error: ‘void*’ is not a pointer-to-object type

I tried to retype it as

```
int (*ptr)[10]=&serV;
x=fabs(m-(double)(*(*ptr +i)))
```

and it worked again for developing program but same error in g++

I am quite new to C and programming as a whole and can't figure out proper solution. Thank you for clearing it out for me

Comment: If this is meant to be C (as per tags), don't compile it with g++ but with gcc. C and C++ are two different languages.

Comment: Actually it is not me compiling with g++ but application testing my program so I cannot change it

Comment: m is defined later in function, the same as the array

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error using the first snippet and g++ and it compiled. Please give some more details. And what do you mean by "m is defined later in function, the same as the array"?